# Calendar Grid with layering of multiple events

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

My attempt at coding an adjusting calendar grid. It seems to work in most cases I've tried (although I haven't tested it exhaustively yet) but my DOM is a bit rusty and I wonder if there's better ways to do what I'm doing here.

`````js
class Session {
    day: number;
    hour: number;
    length: number;
    week: number;
    sem: number;
    module_code: string;
    module_name: string;
    room: string;
    staff: string[];
    cur_id: string | null;
    cur_layer: number | null; 
    constructor(day: number, sem: number, week: number, hour: number, length: number,
        module: string, name: string, room: string, staff: string[]) {
        this.day = day;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.length = length;
        this.week = week;
        this.sem = sem;
        this.module_code = module;
        this.module_name = name;
        this.room = room;
        this.staff = staff;
        this.cur_id = null;
        this.cur_layer = null;
    }
}

let dayNames = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];

const WEEK_COUNT = 12;
const FIRST_HOUR = 9;
const LAST_HOUR = 20;

function idForSlot(day: number, sem: number, week: number, hour: number, layer: number): string {
    return "d" + day + "s" + sem + "w" + week + "h" + hour + "l" + layer;
}

function idForRowHeader(day: number, sem: number, hour: number) {
    return "d" + day + "s" + sem + "h" + hour + "rh";
}

function idForColumnHeader(day: number, sem: number, week: number) {
    return "d" + day + "s" + sem + "w" + week + "h";    
}

function elForSlot(day: number, sem: number, week: number, hour: number, layer: number): HTMLTableCellElement|null {
    return <HTMLTableCellElement|null>document.getElementById(idForSlot(day, sem, week, hour, layer));
}

function layerExists(day: number, sem: number, week: number, layer: number): boolean {
    return elForSlot(day, sem, week, FIRST_HOUR, layer) != null;
}


function createTTGrid(day: number, sem: number) {
    let body = document.getElementById("body")!;

    let tt_div = document.createElement("div");
    tt_div.id = "d" + day + "s" + sem;
    let tt_header = document.createElement("h2");
    tt_header.innerText = dayNames[day-1] + " Semester " + (sem);
    tt_div.append(tt_header);
    
    let table = document.createElement("table");
    table.id = "td" + day + "s" + sem;

    // Column headers
    let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
    headerRow.append(document.createElement("th"));
    for (let i = 1; i <= WEEK_COUNT; i++) {
        let th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerText = "Week " + i;
        th.id = idForColumnHeader(day, sem, i);
        headerRow.append(th);
        // Seperator
        let td = document.createElement("td");
        td.style.background = "black";
        td.style.width = "3px";
        td.style.minWidth = "3px";
        td.rowSpan = LAST_HOUR - FIRST_HOUR + 2;
        headerRow.append(td);
    }

    // Row headers and cells
    table.append(headerRow);
    for (let h=FIRST_HOUR; h<=LAST_HOUR; h++) {
        let row = document.createElement("tr");
        row.id = "d" + day + "s" + sem + "h" + h + "r";
        let th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerText = h + "-" + (h+1);
        th.id = idForRowHeader(day, sem, h);
        row.append(th);
        for (let i=1; i<=WEEK_COUNT; i++) {
            let td = document.createElement("td");
            td.id = idForSlot(day, sem, i, h, 0);
            td.style.border = "1px solid black";
            row.append(td);
        }
        table.append(row);
    }
    tt_div.append(table);
    body.append(tt_div);
}

/**
 * Finds the predecessor element that the cell for a new layer should be inserted after.
 * This is
 *    a) the previous layer in the same week, if it exists
 *    b) the last layer in the previous week that exists, if there is one 
 *    c) if all else fails, the header cell for the row
 * @param day base-0 day number for new layer
 * @param sem base-1 semester number for new layer
 * @param week base-1 semester number for new layer
 * @param hour base-FIRST_HOUR hour number for new layer
 * @param layer intended number of new layer
 * @returns predecessor element
 */
function findNewLayerPredecessor(day: number, sem: number, week: number, hour: number, layer: number): HTMLElement {
    let prevlayerid = layer - 1;
    let prevlayerweek = week;
    let prevLayer = elForSlot(day, sem, prevlayerweek, hour, prevlayerid);

    while (!prevLayer && (prevlayerid > 0 || prevlayerweek > 0)) {
        prevlayerid--;
        if (prevlayerid < 0) {
            // Out of layers in this week, try previous week
            prevlayerweek--;
            let prevweekmaxlayer = 0;
            while (layerExists(day, sem, prevlayerweek, prevweekmaxlayer)) {
                prevweekmaxlayer++;
            }
            prevlayerid = prevweekmaxlayer - 1;
        }
        prevLayer = elForSlot(day, sem, prevlayerweek, hour, prevlayerid); 
    }

    if (prevLayer) {
        return prevLayer;
    } else {
        return document.getElementById(idForRowHeader(day, sem, hour))!;
    }

}

function addTTLayer(day: number, sem: number, week: number) {
    // Find top layer
    let freelayer = 0;
    while (layerExists(day, sem, week, freelayer)) { 
        freelayer++;
    }

    // Increase column span of header
    let colhead = <HTMLTableCellElement>document.getElementById(idForColumnHeader(day, sem, week));
    colhead.colSpan += 1;

    // Add layer
    for (let h=FIRST_HOUR; h<=LAST_HOUR; h++) {
        let newCell = document.createElement("td");
        newCell.id = idForSlot(day, sem, week, h, freelayer);
        newCell.style.border = "1px solid black";
        let prevLayer = findNewLayerPredecessor(day, sem, week, h, freelayer);
        prevLayer.after(newCell);
    }
}

function removeTTLayer(day: number, sem: number, week: number) {
    // Find top layer
    let lastlayer = 0;
    while (layerExists(day, sem, week, lastlayer)) {
        lastlayer++;
    }
    lastlayer--;
    if (lastlayer == 0) return;

    // Decrease column span of header
    let colhead = <HTMLTableCellElement>document.getElementById(idForColumnHeader(day, sem, week));
    colhead.colSpan -= 1;

    // Remove layer
    for (let h=FIRST_HOUR; h<=LAST_HOUR; h++) {
        let layerCell = elForSlot(day, sem, week, h, lastlayer); 
        layerCell?.remove();
    }
}

function addTTEvent(s: Session) {
    let day = s.day, sem = s.sem, week = s.week, hour = s.hour, len = s.length;

    if (s.cur_id) return;

    // Find free layer
    let freelayer = 0;
    let free = false;
    do {
        free = true;
        for (let i=0; i<len; i++) {
            let existingElement = elForSlot(day, sem, week, hour+i, freelayer);
            if (!existingElement) {
                free = false; // Presumably it was part of a prior event with rowspan
                break;
            }
            if (existingElement && existingElement.classList.contains("used")) {
                free = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!free) {
            freelayer++;
            if (!layerExists(day, sem, week, freelayer)) {
                addTTLayer(day, sem, week);
                free = true;                
            }
        }
    } while (!free);

    // Remove empty blocks that will no longer be needed due to rowspan
    if (len > 1) {
        for (let i=1; i<len; i++) {
            let emptyBlock = elForSlot(day, sem, week, hour+i, freelayer);
            if (emptyBlock) emptyBlock.remove();
        }
    }
    
    // Add event
    let eventCell = document.createElement("td");
    eventCell.rowSpan = len;
    eventCell.classList.add("used");
    eventCell.style.border = "1px solid black";
    eventCell.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
    eventCell.innerHTML = s.module_code + "<br>" + s.module_name + "<br>" + s.room;
    let intendedId = idForSlot(day, sem, week, hour, freelayer);
    let oldCell = document.getElementById(intendedId)!;
    oldCell.replaceWith(eventCell);
    oldCell.remove();       
    eventCell.id = intendedId;
    
    s.cur_id = eventCell.id;
    s.cur_layer = freelayer;
}

function removeTTEvent(s: Session) {
    if (!s.cur_id) return;
    if (s.cur_layer == null) return; // Can't do !s.cur_layer because 0 is a valid layer

    
    // Remove event cell
    let eventCellId = s.cur_id;
    let eventCell = document.getElementById(eventCellId)!;
    let newEmptyCell = document.createElement("td");
    newEmptyCell.style.border = "1px solid black";
    eventCell.replaceWith(newEmptyCell);
    eventCell.remove();
    newEmptyCell.id = s.cur_id;
    s.cur_id = null; // Note, keep cur_layer around for empty layer check below
    
    // In case of rowspan, replace empty cells that rowspan previously covered
    if (s.length > 1) {
        for (let h=s.hour+1; h<=s.hour+s.length; h++) {
            let newCell = document.createElement("td");
            newCell.id = idForSlot(s.day, s.sem, s.week, h, s.cur_layer);
            newCell.style.border = "1px solid black";
            let prevLayer = findNewLayerPredecessor(s.day, s.sem, s.week, h, s.cur_layer);
            prevLayer.after(newCell);
        }
    }

    // check if layer became empty
    let layerEmpty = true;
    for (let h=FIRST_HOUR; h<=LAST_HOUR; h++) {
        let cell = elForSlot(s.day, s.sem, s.week, h, s.cur_layer);
        if (cell && cell.classList.contains("used")) {
            layerEmpty = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If layer become empty, remove it
    if (layerEmpty) {
        // Reduce header column span
        let colhead = <HTMLTableCellElement>document.getElementById("d" + s.day + "s" + s.sem + "w" + s.week + "h");
        colhead.colSpan -= 1;
    
        // Remove layer
        for (let h=FIRST_HOUR; h<=LAST_HOUR; h++) {
            let cell = elForSlot(s.day, s.sem, s.week, h, s.cur_layer);
            cell?.remove();
        }
        // Are there layers above?
        let highestLayerAbove = s.cur_layer + 1;
        while (layerExists(s.day, s.sem, s.week, highestLayerAbove)) {
            highestLayerAbove++;
        }
        // If yes, bring cells down a layer
        if (highestLayerAbove > s.cur_layer + 1) {
            for (let h=FIRST_HOUR; h<=LAST_HOUR; h++) {
                for (let l = s.cur_layer+1; l<highestLayerAbove; l++) {
                    let cell = elForSlot(s.day, s.sem, s.week, h, l);
                    if (cell) {
                        cell.id = idForSlot(s.day, s.sem, s.week, h, l-1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    s.cur_layer = null;
}
    
function createAllTTGrids() {
    let body = document.getElementById("body");
    for (let sem=1; sem<3; sem++) {
        for (let day=1; day<6; day++) {
            createTTGrid(day, sem);
        }
    }

    for (let week=1; week<=WEEK_COUNT; week++) { 
        addTTEvent(new Session(1, 2, week, 13, 3, "COMP4005", "Introduction to Object Oriented Programming", "G204", ["Test"]));
        addTTEvent(new Session(1, 2, week, 13, 3, "COMP4005", "Introduction to Object Oriented Programming", "G202", ["Test"]));
        addTTEvent(new Session(1, 2, week, 13, 3, "COMP4005", "Introduction to Object Oriented Programming", "G102", ["Test"]));
        addTTEvent(new Session(1, 2, week, 13, 3, "COMP4005", "Introduction to Object Oriented Programming", "R237", ["Test"]));
    }

    let testsession = new Session(1, 1, 1, 9, 3, "CS2103T", "Software Engineering", "COM1-0210", ["Damith", "Wing"]);
    addTTEvent(testsession);
    let testsession2 = new Session(1, 1, 1, 10, 1, "CS2103T", "Software Engineering", "COM1-0210", ["Damith", "Wing"]);
    addTTEvent(testsession2);
    removeTTEvent(testsession);
}
````
`````